# UTF-8 not encoding html in webview android

Tags: android, encoding

I am using the following code for encoding the html file which is in my asset folder.
    I have gone through various link here but was not successful.
    Here is my piece of code.

```
 WebSettings settings = myWebVeiw.getSettings();
    //settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //myWebVeiw.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    //settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("ISO-8859-1");

    myWebVeiw.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+totaldays+".html");
```

Although it is working for other characters but it is not able to encode â€ .as it prints same on the web view.
Please suggest me what to do.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

You need to set the WebSettings default text encoding to utf-8. And after force the html header charset to utf-8. Exmple:

```
String htmlText = "<html> your page here </html>";
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); // get your webview from the layout
WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
web.loadData(htmlText, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
```

That works for me on android 2.2.1, 4.0.4 and 4.1.2.

Comment: with "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8" worked for me. thanks. ( android 5.0.1 )

Comment: "text/html; charset=utf-8" is the main solver for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could you try and check:

```
myWebVeiw.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/"+totaldays+".html", null, "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

Comment: Yes I have already tried with it but it shows nothing more than a blank page. Can this be the reason that the html may be not correctly decoded.

Answer (score 0):

Not so familiar with webView.
But the browser parse a html charset encoding following:
1.first charset .so please check the totaldays.html 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` 
2. according the content.

Comment: Meta is not helping in my case. as it is static html i guess so I have tried by it..Waiting for the client. I guess this may be the bad html decoding form the client thats why not encoding on android side.