# Android [API 16] WebView not showing crucial UTF-8 characters

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, webview, android-webview

I'm having trouble displaying Tshivenḓa special diacritic characters in Android's WebView for API 16. API 24 works fine. I've tried numerous things: fonts, unicode escape sequences in HTML etc. etc.

See characters here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venda_language#Writing_system

I also tried the following solutions to thee same problem:

[Android. WebView and loadData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961589/android-webview-and-loaddata);

[UTF-8 not encoding html in webview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474223/utf-8-not-encoding-html-in-webview-android);

[Android WebView UTF-8 not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312643/android-webview-utf-8-not-showing);

[Android WebView with garbled UTF-8 characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933069/android-webview-with-garbled-utf-8-characters).

All these answers work except for these Tshivenḓa characters (**ḓ ṱ ḽ ṋ ṅ**
).

I have tried all means of escaping the character and many different encodings. 
(http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x1E12/index.html)

Nothing is working for it. I absolutely can not proceed with my app if I can't get this to work. 
Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered this problem before. Unfortunately Android's default font doesn't support many of these special characters so the only solution I've found is to use a custom font that supports all the characters you need.

Comment: @FelixSFD Please explain what's wrong with my answer? Thanks.